# need to know whether program causes buffer out of bound or infinitely long search if search value is not existing

Tags: c, buffer, buffer-overflow

I have this key-value data struct available on net as a tutorial I think this function may be not right

```
struct DataItem *search(int key) {
   //get the hash 
   int hashIndex = hashCode(key);  
    
   //move in array until an empty 
   while(hashArray[hashIndex] != NULL) {
    
      if(hashArray[hashIndex]->key == key)
         return hashArray[hashIndex]; 
            
      //go to next cell
      ++hashIndex;
        
      //wrap around the table
      hashIndex %= SIZE;
   }        
    
   return NULL;        
}
```

in above code this `while(hashArray[hashIndex] != NULL)` can invoke undefined behavior (correct me if I am wrong because of this `hashIndex %= SIZE;` which returns i.e. 5%=20 == 4 which is correct but that will be infinite loop long life of a program). so I like to know does this program `hashArray` buffer is safe from illegal memory access or buffer out (for `hashArray` array) of bound problem

What i am thinking if it is safe for buffer then what if the value feed for search by user simply does not exists in `hashArray` <-- Question is this correct thing to look at

full code

```
 #include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdbool.h>

#define SIZE 20

struct DataItem {
   int data;   
   int key;
};

struct DataItem* hashArray[SIZE]; 
struct DataItem* dummyItem;
struct DataItem* item;

int hashCode(int key) {
   return key % SIZE;
}

struct DataItem *search(int key) {
   //get the hash 
   int hashIndex = hashCode(key);  
    
   //move in array until an empty 
   while(hashArray[hashIndex] != NULL) {
    
      if(hashArray[hashIndex]->key == key)
         return hashArray[hashIndex]; 
            
      //go to next cell
      ++hashIndex;
        
      //wrap around the table
      hashIndex %= SIZE;
   }        
    
   return NULL;        
}

void insert(int key,int data) {

   struct DataItem *item = (struct DataItem*) malloc(sizeof(struct DataItem));
   item->data = data;  
   item->key = key;

   //get the hash 
   int hashIndex = hashCode(key);

   //move in array until an empty or deleted cell
   while(hashArray[hashIndex] != NULL && hashArray[hashIndex]->key != -1) {
      //go to next cell
      ++hashIndex;
        
      //wrap around the table
      hashIndex %= SIZE;
   }
    
   hashArray[hashIndex] = item;
}

struct DataItem* delete(struct DataItem* item) {
   int key = item->key;

   //get the hash 
   int hashIndex = hashCode(key);

   //move in array until an empty
   while(hashArray[hashIndex] != NULL) {
    
      if(hashArray[hashIndex]->key == key) {
         struct DataItem* temp = hashArray[hashIndex]; 
            
         //assign a dummy item at deleted position
         hashArray[hashIndex] = dummyItem; 
         return temp;
      }
        
      //go to next cell
      ++hashIndex;
        
      //wrap around the table
      hashIndex %= SIZE;
   }      
    
   return NULL;        
}

void display() {
   int i = 0;
    
   for(i = 0; i<SIZE; i++) {
    
      if(hashArray[i] != NULL)
         printf(" (%d,%d)",hashArray[i]->key,hashArray[i]->data);
      else
         printf(" ~~ ");
   }
    
   printf("\n");
}

int main() {
   dummyItem = (struct DataItem*) malloc(sizeof(struct DataItem));
   dummyItem->data = -1;  
   dummyItem->key = -1; 

   insert(1, 20);
   insert(2, 70);
   insert(42, 80);
   insert(4, 25);
   insert(12, 44);
   insert(14, 32);
   insert(17, 11);
   insert(13, 78);
   insert(37, 97);

   display();
   item = search(37);

   if(item != NULL) {
      printf("Element found: %d\n", item->data);
   } else {
      printf("Element not found\n");
   }

   delete(item);
   item = search(37);

   if(item != NULL) {
      printf("Element found: %d\n", item->data);
   } else {
      printf("Element not found\n");
   }
}
```

Comment: `while(hashArray[hashIndex] != NULL)` may never come false so search for ever

Comment: You wonder if `hashArray[hashIndex]` could cause UB. No IMO it can't because your code makes sure that `hashIndex` is always smaller than `SIZE`

Comment: @Jabberwocky can u also please tell how long will it search for input to search if the key simply does not exists. HashArray then will never be null because how array out of bound can be null? What is the stopping criteria for the searching

Comment: Re “5%=20 == 4”:  No, `5 % 20` is 4, so `hashIndex %= SIZE;` with `hashIndex` equal to 5 and `SIZE` equal to 20 sets `hashIndex` to 5.

Comment: @EricPostpischil OK got it but it does not answer my question

Comment: If you set `#define SIZE 3`, your code will loop indefinitely as soon as you try to insert a 4th element (`insert(4, 25);`). There is a bug that needs to be corrected. I didn't look any further, but with a debugger you should quickly find out what's going wrong.

Comment: And this is on top search result I got for searching key value data structure. Now I don't think tutorials are any good source of anything

Comment: @user786 there are good tutorials and there are bad ones. Which tutorial are you talking about? Please share the link, then we may be able to help.

Comment: @Jabberwocky  https://www.tutorialspoint.com/data_structures_algorithms/hash_table_program_in_c.htm

Comment: @user786 [tutorialspoint](https://www.tutorialspoint.com/) has not the best reputation... That code is obviously buggy.

Comment: What about geeksforgeeks.com